# Maximum call stack size exceeded / Too much recursion on Google maps API custom map type with allowed bounds

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create a page using an custom map type image map as a background. I needed to restrict the panning on the image, so that it's not possible to pan past the image, but when panning the map left / right (along the x / longitude axis), the map disappears and I'm getting a "maximum stack size exceeded" (Chrome) or "too much recursion" (Firefox) error.

It turns out I'm not the only one having this issue, but in most of the cases, people had trouble with the decimal signs in the coordinates (, instead of .), but that is not my case since I don't use decimals.

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671480/uncaught-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-google-maps-when-i-try-to) might be my case, but not sure how to go about the undefined latitude. (Mostly because I am quite new to JavaScript in general.)

This is all the code I'm using for the map:

```
    function init() {
    var map;
    var repeatOnAxisX = false;
    var blankTile = "img/map/empty.png";
    var min_zoom = 4,
        max_zoom = 5;

    function getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom) {
        if(!repeatOnAxisX) return coord;
        var totalTiles = 1 << (zoom - min_zoom),
            y = coord.y,
            x = coord.x;
        var originX = 1 << (zoom - 1),
            originY = 1 << (zoom - 1);
        if(y < originX || y >= originX + totalTiles || x < originX || x >= originX + totalTiles) {
            return null;
        }
        x -= originX;
        y -= originY;
        return {
            x : x,
            y : y
        };
    }

    var customMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
            var normalizedCoord = getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom);
            if(normalizedCoord) {
                return "img/map/" + zoom + "/" + normalizedCoord.x + "/" + normalizedCoord.y + ".png";
            } else {
                return blankTile;
            }
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        maxZoom: max_zoom,
        minZoom: min_zoom,
        name: "My Image Map"
    });

    var mapDiv = document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(-1, -1),
        myOptions = {
            zoom: 5,
            center: myCenter,
            streetViewControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds: ["custom"]
            }
        };

    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, myOptions);
    map.mapTypes.set("custom", customMapType);
    map.setMapTypeId("custom");

    // Setting up the panning restriction
    var allowedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(-67, -74),
        new google.maps.LatLng(67, 74)
    );

    var boundLimits = {
        maxLat: allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
        maxLng: allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
        minLat: allowedBounds.getSouthWest().lat(),
        minLng: allowedBounds.getSouthWest().lng()
    };

    var lastValidCenter = map.getCenter();
    var newLat, newLng;
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "center_changed", function() {
        center = map.getCenter();
        if(allowedBounds.contains(center)) {
            // still within valid bounds, so save last valid position
            lastValidCenter = map.getCenter();
            return;
        }
        newLat = lastValidCenter.lat();
        newLng = lastValidCenter.lng();
        if(center.lng() > boundLimits.minLng && center.lng() < boundLimits.maxLng) {
            newLng = center.lng();
        }
        if(center.lat() > boundLimits.minLat && center.lat() < boundLimits.maxLat) {
            newLat = center.lat;
        }
        map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(newLat, newLng));
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", init);
```

(I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125065/how-do-i-limit-panning-in-google-maps-api-v3) solution to restrict the panning.)

**EDIT:** Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thosetinydreams/8UDYL/) of the problem.

Any ideas / help is really appreciated! Than you!

Comment: Add a jsfiddle please

Comment: @Zarich: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/thosetinydreams/8UDYL/) it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your center_changed listener where you check if your newLat and newLng are out of bounds, you assign to newLng the return value (number) of center.lng(), but to newLat you assign the function center.lat:

```
if(center.lng() > boundLimits.minLng && center.lng() < boundLimits.maxLng) {
    newLng = center.lng();
}
if(center.lat() > boundLimits.minLat && center.lat() < boundLimits.maxLat) {
    newLat = center.lat;
}
```

Obviously, you need to call center.lat:

```
newLat = center.lat();
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
I think I've been staring at the code for so long that I completely missed it..